# R: border removal for OCR

Tags: r, ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to use the tesserect package in R to extract some information from some printed forms. However, I'm finding it difficult to deal with instances where some characters have gone over the form margins.

[image: sample form]

After reading some tutorials, it seems like removing borders could improve my results. Is there anyway I could do this using packages availbe to R. I have looked at the package "magick" and that does not seem to have a function to detect borders. 
Lastly, if there is another approach to deal with this issue, please let me know. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you are right, definitely removing lines/grids from image will improve the OCR accuracy.

Assuming you have only horizontal and vertical lines in the image along with printed texts, here is my my approach which you can give a shot.

1) Find the horizontal lines with length above a given threshold value according to lines present in your images.

2) Find the line thickness

3) Scan through the line pixels and delete them if there are not black pixels above and below the line pixel. This step will avoid deleting character pixels while removing the line.

4) Use the same 1, 2 for vertical lines.

5) Again scan through the vertical lines and delete the line pixels if there are not black pixels in left and right positions of the line pixel.